# Storing a preprocessed Scrabble dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have recently been working on creating a Scrabble type game in Python. In this game you have a rack of tiles that you can use in combination with tiles that are already on the board to create new words.

In order to create an AI for the game I thought it might be useful to preprocess the word dictionary for quicker lookup time. I preprocess it as follows:

1. "Sort" the letters of each word in ascending order. So "cat" becomes "act" and "batter" becomes "abertt". Use these "Sorted words" as the keys of the preprocessed dictionary
2. Set the value of each key to be the list of words (in alphabetically ascending order) that have letter frequencies exactly the same as the key.

As an example if my word list is:

```
["act","cat","god","dog","good"]
```

The processed dictionary would be:

```
{"act":["act","cat"], "dgo":["dog","god"],"dgoo":["good"]}
```

What I now need to do is store this processed dictionary so that I do not have to recalculate it every time. I currently have two ideas:

1. Use the `pickle` module and `dump` the dictionary to a binary file.
2. Output to a text file so that each line is in the form "KEY VAL1 VAL2 ..." and load it manually.

Which approach should I use? I have heard mixed opinions about the `pickle` module, but the text file approach does not feel quite right either. Is there a better option to suit my needs?

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: What are your criteria for *"better"*?

Comment: My main concerns are efficiency and code stability. But I am also interested to know if there is a particular method that is considered the "pythonic" way to do things

Comment: The pythonic way to persist arbitrary objects is `pickle` (I'm not sure what *"mixed opinions"* you've heard, or if they're relevant to your use case), but if you want the result to be human-readable JSON might be a good alternative. Just pick one, build your code so whichever you choose is easy to switch out and revisit the decision later if you actually find a problem.

Comment: I think your idea of preprocessing the word dictionary is likely premature optimization (see [when to optimize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize)) — so worrying about how optimize the optimization is even more questionable.